# More log files then error.log and out.log in pm2

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

Currently pm2 logs console.log, .debug, .info to out.log and console.error, .warn, .trace to error.log

Is there a way to have the different messages go to different files so I would like to have a warn.log for just warning or a debug.log for just me debug messages.

Comment: pm2 works with stdout and stderr streams to segregate logs. I don't think there can be custom streams like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [nothing that I can see](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/) in the PM2 that supports this functionality- I think they have intentionally kept this interface simple.

I would suggest using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)- at the start of your process, create a map of winston transports like;

```js
log = []
log.component1 = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'component1.log' })
  ]
});
```

You can also include [transformers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#creating-custom-formats) in the console logger to prefix your stdout logs based on which component it is coming from.

Comment: I have been using Winston with winston-rotate-daily-file and I need to be able to generate new log files each day for 7 day and delete the logs for those 7 day at the end of 7 days, could I use Winston to generate the log files and use pm2-logrotate to delete the logs at the end?

Comment: 1. It seems like `winston-rotate-daily-file` automatically handles deleting the logs.  Look at the `maxFiles` parameter.

2. Personally, I would just use you server for logrotate functionality; it has more defined behavior and allows you to capture other logs as well. (https://www.tecmint.com/install-logrotate-to-manage-log-rotation-in-linux/)